# Largest possible data type

Tags: c++, types, c++17

I was writing a C++ code and I found out that the input might be all the way up to `10^25`, which as far as I know exceeds **unsigned long long**.

This raised 2 questions in my mind, and the articles out there aren't quite helpful:

1. What is the **max size** of the *biggest data type* in C++? I know the biggest data type is ull, but many sources contradict each other, saying that it's on 4 bits, but then int is on 32, and that's ... not coherent, since there is also `long int`, `long long`, and those have to be stored on some **power of 2 number of bits**.
2. How can one work with numbers above that "limit"? Can you define some `class` that stores huge values by splitting them into pieces...but what's a way to even read that? You have to save into something, and reading character by character doesn't go too well.

**`*Thank you in advance for your help! I wish you all a fantastic day!*`**

Comment: For large numbers, you can use array of array. Each index will be used to store the ith place number.

Comment: This really depends... What is the actual problem you are solving?  Do you actually need integer precision for the entire range?  Instead of asking what  the largest (presumably) integer is, maybe you should state the problem you need to solve.

Comment: _"but many sources contradict each other, saying that it's on 4 bits, but then int is on 32"_ - probably one source mentioned 4 **bytes** which are 32 bits.

Comment: `Unsigned long long` is at least **64** bits, not 32. Still, 10^25 > 8^25 == 2^75

Comment: @churill Nope, 4 bits. I understand your perfectly logical assumption, but I found places where it says 4 bits. Of course, this can't be true, that's just 0000 So the maximum value, reached at 1111 is 15.

Comment: @AndrewFNAF Yep, 4 bit `long`s are definitively not allowed by the standard, nor would they make much sense. Then it's a typo in that source.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no straight forward answer to your question. The build in types may (with few exceptions) differ in size see depending on compiler and architecture [(check cppreference.com for more information)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). The contradiction you mentioned may come from a discussion of typical values. Maybe they said 4bytes and 32bits, which would be the same thing (but this is me speculating now and unimportant to answering your question).
2. There are however libraries which support "arbitrary" sizes like the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Which library is the best to use is strongly problem dependent.

Comment: The `char` type has size `1` (in the sense that `sizeof(char)` is `1`) on every architecture.   The standard defines that.

Comment: @Peter yes indeed. The C++-Standard guarantees: 

    1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long). Hence I wrote 'may differ', cause writing all the picky details in an answers would end up like the existing article on cpp-reference.

Comment: @Peter Ok, now I see why this is bad phrasing :D   sorry

Answer (score 1):

1. Sizes of types are not consistent. Well, most types. There are actually several [fixed-size integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), the largest of which is `int64_t` or `uint64_t`, which, as you may have guessed, is 64 bits. They may not always be present though.
2. That's up to you. There are already libraries that can handle this for you if that's what you want. Yes, splitting them up is the obvious way. You could represent them as strings and perform calculations the way you were taught in third grade math (with overflow digits and stuff). A more concise (and memory-efficient) way would be to split the numbers into something smaller, like `uint32_t`. Performing operations in the larger type (`uint64_t`) would take care of the overflow bits.

.

```
struct myuint96 {
    uint32_t data[3];
};

myuint96 operator+(const myuint96& left, const myuint96& right) {
    myuint96 result;
    uint64_t sum = (uint64_t)left.data[0] + right.data[0];
    result.data[0] = sum & UINT32_MAX;
    // This would be done in a for loop for bigger types
    sum = (sum & ~(uint64_t)UINT32_MAX) >> 32 + left.data[1] + right.data[1];
    result.data[1] = sum & UINT32_MAX;
    sum = (sum & ~(uint64_t)UINT32_MAX) >> 32 + left.data[2] + right.data[2];
    result.data[2] = sum & UINT32_MAX;
    // Here we don't care about overflow bits, or you can throw an exception
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Having `myuint64`, but relying on `std::uint64_t` for implementation ^_^

Comment: Of course, this is just an example to show how the overflow bits can be handled for arbitrarily large types

Comment: `myuint96` would be more relevant.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your advice,
I wonder though, how do you even get them into the program? I meeaaan, you have to do
cin>>x or scanf(x), but if the value is too big, it'll throw one big messy error

Comment: @AndrewFNAF Well... If you choose to represent your number as a string, the answer is obvious. As for numbers, it gets trickier. If your input was binary or hexadecimal, it's quite straightforward (split the input string into correctly sized portions and parse each separately). If your input is decimal, it gets worse. The only optimization I can think of here is abusing the fact that any multiple of 10 is divisible by 2, any multiple of 100 is divisible by 4, etc. (in practice, that means you don't have to care about anything before the n-th bit after you've parsed the n-th digit)

Answer (score 1):

About your questions

1. The maximum size is determined by your RAM (or even more if you choose to load dynamically from hard drive)
2. Well, you can read your number character by character, and insert each character into the resulting class separately

And BTW, if you are using g++ compiler and want to store 10**25, you may try to use [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)(which is compiler extension, not part of the standart)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the latter part of your question, because I feel it's easier to answer:

> How can one work with numbers above that "limit"?

Use (or write) a library. You've got the basic idea right: split a huge number in different parts. One libray I've worked with is [libgmp](https://gmplib.org) but there are many others.

---

The first part of your question is bit more tricky in my opinion.

> What is the max size of the biggest data type in C++?

It depends on some factors what the "biggest" data type is. It's different on different platforms and it depends on wether you focus on integral types only or take floating point numbers into account. Because of your latter statements I assume you are talking about integral types only.

In general: You can use `sizeof(some_type)` to get the size in bytes of a type or `std::numeric_limits<some_type>::max()` to check the largest value a given type can represent ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)).

> I know the biggest data type is ull, but many sources contradict each other, saying that it's on 4 bits

Probably that source mentioned **4 bytes** (= 32 bits) rather than 4 **bits**.

> but then int is on 32,

On all platforms I've worked with that's true, but the standard only requires `int` to be *at least* 16 bits wide (see this [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)).

> and that's ... not coherent, since there is also `long int`, `long long`

`long` and `long int` are the same. Also `long long` is the same as `long long int` and, yes, they are allowed to be inconsistent or redundant (probably a suboptimal wording though).

`long` must be *at least* 32 bits wide and `long long` *at least* 64. ([reference as above](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types))

> and those have to be stored on some power of 2 number of bits.

That's true from a technical perspective, for basically all modern platforms. **I think** the standard would also work for systems that are not based on powers of 2, for example where a byte has 7 or 9 bits (That's way out of my league though). I'm not sure if, why or where, you think this would not be the case here, maybe this problem was already covered in a previous point.

Answer (score -1):

- > What is the max size of the biggest data type in C++?

  From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t:

  > `std::size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array). A type whose size cannot be represented by `std::size_t` is ill-formed (since C++14).

  So max size of the biggest data type in C++ should be less than max value of `std::size_t`.

  [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.17) recommends a minimum of 262144 for the limit.

  You might see from https://github.com/fritzone/cpp-stresstest#size-of-an-object---sizeofanobject

  current limits from some compilers:

  ```
  gcc     clang   msvc    intel  
  2097152 2097152 524288  2097152
  ```
- > How can one work with numbers above that "limit"?

There are libraries for big-number, there are basically array of integer types.